# ¿Como cambio mi autenticacion de usuario a otro columna en la db como username en laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

Lo que quiero es cambiar de usar la columna "email" para loguear utilice la columna "name".

Segui este tutorial en youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PRc1M3mLPk

Hago exactamente lo que el hace pero fracaso en el intento. ¿Alguna sugerencia del porque?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estás usando el método de login que trae por defecto laravel, basta con crear una función, en archivo de login que se encuentra en la carpeta:
App -> Http -> Controllers -> Auth

```
public function username()
{
    return field;
}
```

donde `field` es el campo a usar en la base de datos, ya que el método `auth` de laravel llama a esa función para saber cuál es el campo a leer en base de datos.